# Android MediaPlayer error (1, 9100) - Lg L7

Tags: android, debugging, media-player, android-videoview, lg

I have a weird problem:
I have a VideoView on an activity, i get a xml file from my server, parse it and get the path of the video (i don't post the url video, because are adult content), i set the url to the videoview.

All works fine in all devices i have: xperia zr, Lg Optimus L5, Xperia tipo, htc desire hd, asus TF101, even on emulators, but on the optimus L7 i have a toast error (this video cannot reproduce) when try to play the video and i get this log:

```
06-04 10:13:49.620: E/MediaPlayer(12861): error (1, 9100)
06-04 10:13:49.620: W/MediaPlayer(12861): info/warning (1, 9100)
06-04 10:13:49.640: E/MediaPlayer(12861): Error (1,9100)
06-04 10:13:49.640: D/VideoView(12861): Error: 1,9100
06-04 10:13:49.730: I/MediaPlayer(12861): Info (1,9100)
```

What means this error??

More info: if i copy the video (the same i get by http) on his sdcard, and try to reproduce on this videoview on local, it's works perfect.

I try to reproduce video by youtube and get the same toast error (this video cannot reproduce), but different log error `error(1, 0).`

Android Ver. = 4.0.3 | 
Model Device = LG-P700

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!, was a problem with screen Width and Height.
I have 2 videos sizes (W:720, H:540) for larges screens and (W:480, H:360) for smalls screens.

All devices i tried that are greater than small size, are greater than large size, so no problem.

The problem comes with L7 that have 480w x 800h pixels screen, so it's greater than small but not to enough from large, so seems couldn't resize the video to the large size and crash...

If i set the small size video, everything works fine.